# Libqtgui4 is not available (Has no installation candidate)

Tags: picamera

I am trying to run this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libqt4-test python3-pyqt5
```

But I receive these errors:

```
Package libqtgui4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.

E: Package 'libqtgui4' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libqtwebit4
E: Unable to locate package libqt4-test
```

I was trying to follow this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59080094/raspberry-pi-and-opencv-cant-install-libhdf5-100

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5test5
```

Instead of `sudo apt-get install libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libqt4-test`, If you are trying to install `opencv` on a Raspberry Pi 3B

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).